# Can Eclipse send mail when a breakpoint is hit?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, email, breakpoints

I would like to configure Eclipse to send mail when a breakpoint is hit.

Can this be done?

Comment: Probably not OOTB, but should be possible to write a plug-in to do that. Just curious, why in the world would you want to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can make it a conditional breakpoint and write some code in the condition to send the mail. But what is your use case?